# Take list element, check if it contains only digits, and if so, convert to int class

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I have some math expressions in a list, like `["2", "*", "2"]`, `["3", "+", "pi"]`. Now, I want the list elements that contain ONLY digits to be detected, and be converted to integers. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

`newList = [int(i) for i in oldList if i.isdigit()]`

Comment: You don't need to call `str(i)` on strings. `i.isdigit()` will work fine.

Comment: I did that thinking if there will be an int in list beforehand. like [1,'*','2']